# "Why is the cookie not functioning as expected in a React Native WebView when making a POST request?"

Tags: react-native, cookies, webview

I am facing an issue with cookies in a React Native WebView when attempting to make a POST request. Despite setting the necessary headers and parameters, the cookie does not appear to be functioning as expected. When I inspect the network requests, I can see that the cookie is not being included in the POST request headers.

I have tried various approaches, including setting the useWebKit prop to true, explicitly setting the `javaScriptEnabled` prop,`sharedCookiesEnabled`,`thirdPartyCookiesEnabled`,`originWhitelist={["*"]}` and even testing with different versions of React Native, but the issue persists.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem with cookies not working properly in a React Native WebView, specifically with POST requests? Any insights into potential solutions or debugging steps would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also fetched this issue before. The I solved this way. Hope this solution will help you.

First you have to get [cookies](https://github.com/react-native-cookies/cookies) after login and save it in [AsyncStorage](https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage) or [Redux](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux) then pass the `cookieString` in `modifiedHeaders` object.

> N.B.: Don't forget to uninstall the app before running this code

**Full code**

```js
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import WebView from 'react-native-webview';

const MyWebView = () => {
  const webViewRef = useRef(null);

  // Intercept and modify requests before they are executed
  const handleShouldStartLoadWithRequest = (request) => {
    // Check if the request URL contains a specific pattern
    if (request.url.includes('https://example.com/your/endpoint')) {
      const modifiedHeaders = {
        ...request.headers,
        Cookie: 'cookieString' // Set your desired cookie header here
      };

      const modifiedHeadersJSON = JSON.stringify(modifiedHeaders);

      // Load the modified request in the WebView
      webViewRef.current.injectJavaScript(`
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('${request.method}', '${request.url}');
        
        // Set the modified headers
        const modifiedHeaders = ${modifiedHeadersJSON};
        for (let key in modifiedHeaders) {
          xhr.setRequestHeader(key, modifiedHeaders[key]);
        }
        
        xhr.send();
      `);

      return false; // Prevent the WebView from loading the original request
    }

    // Allow other requests to proceed as usual
    return true;
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <WebView
        ref={webViewRef}
        source={{ uri: 'https://example.com' }}
        onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={handleShouldStartLoadWithRequest}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default MyWebView;
```